# square brackets followed by parentheses expression in vuex ( javascript )

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, vue.js, vuex

I find this expresion in some project using vuex:

```
[SET_BREADCRUMB](state, payload) {
      state.commit(SET_BREADCRUMB, payload);
    }
```

Please someone explain me what is here?
Usually [] this is  array notation.
But i don't understand why is followed by () like a function.

Comment: You’re probably talking about this pattern? https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#using-constants-for-mutation-types

Comment: It is a commonly seen pattern to use constants for mutation types in various Flux implementations. This allows the code to take advantage of tooling like linters, and putting all constants in a single file allows your collaborators to get an at-a-glance view of what mutations are possible in the entire application: